# Display django models property in admin

Tags: django, django-models

While I was working in django models i tried to implement calculations part in django models. But I don't know how to how to show that calculated amount in the django admin side too"

[Please see this image for clarifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBuxv.png)

This is the code I had implemented. I need to add Extra_Payment and Total_Payment in django admin side.

```
class Salarie(models.Model):
    Employee_Name = models.ForeignKey('Employee_Detail', models.DO_NOTHING,primary_key=True)
    Dept_Name = models.ForeignKey('Department', models.DO_NOTHING)
    Basic_Salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Extra_Hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @property
    def Extra_Payment(self):
        return self.Extra_Hours * 350

    Bonus = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @property
    def Total_Payment(self):
        return self.Extra_Payment + self.Basic_Salary + self.Bonus

    m = (
        ("January","January"),("February","February"),("March","March"),("April","April"),("May","May"),("June","June"),("July","July"),("August","August"),("September","September"),("October","October"),("November","November"),("December","december")
    )
    Month = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices= m)
    Year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    Status = models.BooleanField()
    Paid_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Employee_Name)
```

Comment: Maybe this might help you... https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/calculated_fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display calculated amount i.e. Extra_Payment and Total_Payment with the help of **ModelAdmin.readonly_fields**

```
# admins.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Salarie


class SalarieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('Extra_Payment', 'Total_Payment')

admin.site.register(Salarie, SalarieAdmin)
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) for more details.